# how to find the missing cards,I tried to use 'find function',but it will print all the cards (not the missing cards)

Tags: c++

**Problem Statement**
A boy wants to play card games. However, he only has `n` cards, even though there should be `52` (he doesn't have a Joker).
In the first line, the number of cards n is given (n ≤ 52).

**Output**.
Print missing cards. As in the input format, each card should print a character and an integer, separated by a space character on a line.input gives like n=47,s 1 s 4...he lost some cards ,how to find them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

vector<string> suits = {"S", "H", "C", "D"};
    vector<string> ranks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
    int n;
    cin >> n;
   vector<string> existingCards(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> existingCards[i];
    }
for (string suit : suits) {
        for (string rank : ranks) {
            string card = suit + " " + rank;
            if (find(existingCards.begin(), existingCards.end(), card) == existingCards.end()) {
                cout << card << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Expected Output**
S 1
H 3
H 7
C 12
D 8
But always prints every card right now.

Comment: for (string suit : suits) {
        for (string rank : ranks) {
            string card = suit + " " + rank;
            if (find(existingCards.begin(), existingCards.end(), card) == existingCards.end()) {
                cout << card << endl;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: it drives me crazy

Comment: ***[Edit]*** your question to improve it, like adding your [mre]. Don't post comments. And pay attention to the tags you add, and the language you're really program in.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. I also recommend that you read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put your code into the question, not in comments. That said, your code snippets is not C but C++. You should adjust the tag accordingly when you add the code you have to your question

Comment: Share the input format as well, its not clear right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in `cin >> existingCards[i]` since it will not read the entire line, hence instead of reading `S 1` you will only read `S` and next for loop will read `1`.
Instead use `cin >> suit >> rank` and then `existingCards[i] = suit + " " + rank;` to fix the issue as shown below.

https://ideone.com/smYucB

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> suits = {"S", "H", "C", "D"};
    vector<string> ranks = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"};
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> existingCards(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        string suit, rank;
        cin >> suit >> rank;
        string card = suit + " " + rank;
        existingCards[i] = card;
    }
    for (string suit : suits) {
        for (string rank : ranks) {
            string card = suit + " " + rank;
            if (find(existingCards.begin(), existingCards.end(), card) == existingCards.end()) {
                cout << card << endl;
            }
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I got it right when you said it. I am a freshman in college, so I am not very familiar with it yet. Thank you very much.